# ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2){"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back.

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-weld

Hi Every one i have some problem with jboss-as-7.1.1.When i deploy axis2.war in jboss-5.1, jboss-6.1 it's work fine but when i deploy in jboss-as-7.1.1 i am getting error

My error log is given below:-

```
12:03:27,851 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "axis2.war"
12:03:30,721 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry xpp3.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-run-1.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:03:30,724 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry stax-api.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-run-1.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:03:30,727 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry wstx-asl.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-run-1.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:03:30,735 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry jaxws-rt.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-tools-2.1.3.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:03:30,738 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry jaxb-xjc.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-tools-2.1.3.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:03:30,743 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry relaxngDatatype.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-tools-2.1.3.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:03:30,747 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry bcel.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-bind-1.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:03:30,750 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry jibx-run.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-bind-1.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:03:30,753 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry xpp3.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-bind-1.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:03:30,756 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry stax-api.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-bind-1.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:03:30,758 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry wstx-asl.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-bind-1.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:03:30,762 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:03:30,766 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:03:30,769 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:03:30,771 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry jaxb1-impl.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:03:30,777 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/mail-1.4.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:03:30,792 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry xercesImpl.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:03:30,798 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:03:30,807 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry serializer.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:03:31,112 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."axis2.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."axis2.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "axis2.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.axis2.war:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/axis2/webapp/AdminAgent;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis2.webapp.AdminAgent from [Module "deployment.axis2.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 15 more

12:03:31,193 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "axis2.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"axis2.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"axis2.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"axis2.war\""}}
12:03:31,318 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment axis2.war in 124ms
12:03:31,320 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."axis2.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."axis2.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "axis2.war"

12:03:31,336 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"axis2.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"axis2.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"axis2.war\""}}}}
```

Any one have time please help me.
Thanx

Answer (score 1):

The class loading  in JBoss AS7 is different comparing to previous versions (6, 5 and so on). You should avoid putting all you libraries to web-inf/lib folder but instead of this use modules and dependencies. Please read the details [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7)